# JQuery flippy plugin Not Triggered on Click Event

Tags: jquery, flippy

I have a small problem with `flippy` plugin  tag with jQuery Flippy plugin 
http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/

I have one div with `p` tag

```
<div id="divID">
<p id="pID" class="someClass">Some text
<a id="aID" href="#">Some text</a> </p>
</div>
```

and event handler on my page

```
$("#aID").click(function(){
    var content = $("#divID").html();
$("#divID").flippy({
    direction:"LEFT",
    duration: "500",
    verso: content

 });    
});
```

The problem is that, when I click the  element to flip div, the div are flipped,but the click function doesn't handle another click.

I can flip the div only once. When I place the "a" element outside of the div, I can flipped as long as i want, but this is not my objective.

Can anyone advice me please.

Comment: could u make fiddle for this at jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all my event listeners registered in div are not available after flipping div, I register this listeners again after flipping

```
$(document).on("click", "#element", function(){ do something});
```

i.e:

In my JSP: `$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#register").click(function() {
    switchRegister();

});

$("#forgPass").click(function() {
    forgPass();
});

});`
```

And in .js file:

/*
 * Switch Login Screen to Register Screen
 */

function switchRegister() {
    var mainContent = $("#LoginBox").html();

```
$("#btnLogIn").prop('value', regText);
$("#regProfile").hide();
$("#regPass").hide();

$("#iconName").show();
$("#regText").show();
$("#goBack").show();

var content = $("#LoginBox").html();

$("#LoginBox").flippy({
    direction:"LEFT",
    duration: "500",
    verso: content,
    onFinish: function() {
        $("#goBack").on("click", function(){
            $("#LoginBox").empty();
            backToLogin(mainContent, "right");
        });
    }
 });
```

}

/*
 * Back to Login Screen
 */

function backToLogin(content,direction) {

```
if(direction == "right") {
    console.log("direction RIGHT");
    $("#LoginBox").flippy({
        direction:"RIGHT",
        duration: "500",
        verso: content,
        onFinish: function(){
            $(document).on("click", "#register", function(){
                switchRegister();
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#forgPass", function(){
                forgPass();
            });
        }
     });
} else {
    console.log(" direction Bottom");
    $("#LoginBox").flippy({
        direction:"BOTTOM",
        duration: "500",
        verso: content,
        onFinish: function(){
            $("#register").on("click", function(){
                switchRegister();
            });
            $("#forgPass").on("click", function(){
                forgPass();
            });
        }
     });
}
```

}

/*
 * Forgot password 
 */
function forgPass() {

```
var mainContent = $("#LoginBox").html();

$("#btnLogIn").prop('value', passText);
$("#regPass").hide();
$("#regProfile").hide();
$("#iconPass").hide();
$("#regText").hide();
$("#goBack").show();

var content = $("#LoginBox").html();

$("#LoginBox").flippy({
    direction:"TOP",
    duration: "500",
    verso: content,
    onFinish: function() {
        $("#goBack").on("click", function(){
            $("#LoginBox").empty();
            backToLogin(mainContent, "bottom");
        });
    }
 });
```

}

Comment: I have the same problem. This solution is a forced one. It doesn't fix the original problem. Maybe the plugin author must be contacted. I'm using the same solution to solve it until the plugin be repaired. I started a bounty in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15885500/2324311).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`jQuery Flip`](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) and [`Git Hub URL`](https://github.com/roncioso/Flip-jQuery)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Unfortunately the result is the same. After fliping the div, the listeners inside are not available for click() events, registered in javascript

Comment: I will share you jsfiddle.net asap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r6Twt/  Unfortunately I can't find URI to Flippy plugin and add file jquery.flippy.js

Comment: I found solution.  Because all my event listeners registered in div are not available after flipping div for some strange reason, I register this listeners again after flipping   `$(document).on("click", "#register", function(){
   switchRegister();`  Thanks for support